# Hiding folders from search engines

Tags: search, web-crawler, search-engine

How to mark folder hidden for all search engines?

How many alternatives are there?

Which one is the most reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent search engines from visiting certain directories/urls it is common practice to use robots.txt. This is a file that search engines take a look at before spidering your website.

#### robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /secret/
```

**This file should be placed in your website root. For example `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`**

There are two important considerations when using /robots.txt:

- robots can ignore your /robots.txt. Especially malware robots that scan the web for security vulnerabilities, and email address harvesters used by spammers will pay no attention.
- the /robots.txt file is a publicly available file. Anyone can see what sections of your server you don't want robots to use.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Where should put it robots.txt file? The secret folder?

Comment: In your website root - For example: `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want the **manager folder** hide. 

Manager folder path: **/public_html/manager/**

I need to put here **/public_html/robots.txt/** ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does this process apply to all search engines?

Comment: It does. It is kind of a standard.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't hide from all search engines?

Comment: To be more clear. Yes, this will hide the folder from all search engines.